# Java Thread argument

Tags: java, multithreading, this

On my way to learn threads, this is working as intended

```
public class Game implements Runnable{

    //FIELDS
    private Thread t1;
    boolean running;

    //METHODS   

    public void start(){
        running = true;
        t1 = new Thread(this);
        t1.start();
    }


    public void run(){
        while (running){
            System.out.println("runnin");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(17);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



}
```

And then, when I change the thread argument into

```
t1=new Thread (new Game());
```

The program doesn't enter the run method anymore.
Shouldn't they be the same? What should be the other way to substitute the "this" keyword?

EDIT: I'm calling the start method from another class.

Even setting the running variable to true after the instance has been created, it remains false:

```
public void start(){
    t1 = new Thread(new Game());
    running = true;
    t1.start();
}
```

Comment: Can you show the missing codes? Where are you calling `start()` from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It enters the `run()` method, but it immediately returns from it, because the run method loops while `running` is true.

When calling `new Game()`, you're constructing a new different instance of Game, whose `running` field is false. So the loop doesn't loop at all:

```
public void start(){
    running = true; // set this.running to true
    t1 = new Thread(new Game()); // construct a new Game. This new Game has another, different running field, whose value is false 
    t1.start(); // start the thread, which doesn't do anything since running is false
}
```

Change it to

```
public void start(){
    Game newGame = new Game();
    newGame.running = true;
    t1 = new Thread(newGame);
    t1.start();
}
```

and it will do what you expect.

Comment: Spot on JB, that was the problem, as the debugger demonstrated. Thanks. But it remain false, even if invert the lines and set running to true after the Game instance has been created. Where sould I declare the running as true? Maybe my approach is wrong but I just would like how to avoid "this" keyword for study purposes.

Comment: It's not clear. Edit your question, and show your updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Not the same, in the first case if you call start() you'll create a new thread and start it, but when you use new Thread(new Game()) you need to call start() on the new thread.

Try this:

```
t1=new Thread (new Game());
t1.start();
```

Comment: -1: because the thread is being started, and the guess is thus wrong

Answer (score 0):

It enters the run method but the variable 'running' is initialized to false for the new object created using new Game(). Hence, it does not print anything on the console.

If you want to create a thread for another instance of the object , you could try the following :

```
public class Game implements Runnable{

//FIELDS
private Thread t1;
boolean running;

//Constructor to set the running boolean
public Game(boolean running)
{
   this.running = running;
}


//METHODS   

public void start(){
    running = true;
    t1 = new Thread(new Game(running));
    t1.start();
}


public void run(){
    while (running){
        System.out.println("runnin");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(17);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Game implements Runnable{
//FIELDS
private Thread t1;
boolean running;
//METHODS   
public void start(){
running = true;
t1 = new Thread(new Game());
t1.start();
}
public void run(){
running=true;
while (running){
System.out.println("runnin");
try {
Thread.sleep(17);
}
catch (InterruptedException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
}
class another{
public static void main(String s[]){
Game t=new Game();
t.start();
}
}
```